# Dependence of Sobolev embedding theorem constant on smoothness

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, embeddings, interpolation-spaces

Assume that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is "nice" enough and $k$ is a positive real number. Using the Sobolev embedding theorem, we can get that
$$
\|f\|_{W^{0,2d/(d-2k)}\ \ \ \ \ (\Omega)} \leq C \|f\|_{W^{k,2}(\Omega)}. 
$$
for some $C$ depending on $k$ and others.

Now I want to know the relationship between $C$ and $k$, especially I want to know if $C$ is bounded when $k \to d/2$. If $C$ is not bounded, can we bound $C$ by a function about $k$?

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you mean $k \to \frac{d}{2}$ instead of $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @Keba Thank you! I want $k \to d/2$ and the smooth index in the left side to $+\infty$.

Comment: If you don't want the best possible constant, then all you have to do is to work through a proof of the Sobolev inequality and keep track of how the constant changes from ine to line. It will definitely be continuous with respect to each parameters (it's harder to write formulas that depend discontinuously on the parameters). But the constant will blow up as $k\rightarrow d/2$, because I don't believe the inequality holds when $k=d/2$. I don't know anything about the sharp constant. I only know what happens for the $W^{k,1}$ Sobolev inequality.